# Using compareTo() to sort a LinkedList alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a LinkedList which holds data for a student, it has a name, gpa, and ID# for each student, and each student is a Node in the LinkedList. I want to sort my LinkedList alphabetically by their names, but I'm not really understanding how to use CompareTo() to sort. So right now I have my compareTo method using the string compareTo of the current name.compareTo(name_of_inputStudent). So in my sort method how would i utilize that output to sort my array? I don't really understand how that would help me identify which string belongs in which position on the LinkedList.

Comment: can you show the code you already have?

Comment: See [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

Comment: You probably need to implement comparable within your container class and override compareTo() method. Then you can call Collections.sort() on your list to sort the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use Java library, you don't have to do anything else: simply pass your list to `sort`, which uses `compareTo` automatically when you do not pass a separate comparer. Note that sorting a `LinkedList` is more expensive than sorting an `ArrayList`, because most advanced comparison-based sorting algorithms require random access to the list, which is O(1) for an array list, but O(n) for a linked list.

If you set on implementing your own sorting algorithm, `compareTo` lets you determine if two objects are in a sorted position or if they should switch places:

- If an object closer to the front of the list is compared to an object further away from the front, and the result is negative or zero, the objects are in a proper order in relation to each other
- If the result is positive, the objects should change places so that the one further away from the start would be closer to the start.

These two considerations alone are sufficient to implement [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `Collections.sort(...)`. You can find the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)). To use the method your `Student` class must implement `Comparable` interface. So, you have to select a sorting criteria for your `Student` class and implement it into the `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

In you Node class of the LinkedList, implement Comparable interface and override compareTo method. Then you can use Collections.sort(List).
Since you are using a linked list, sorting will be inefficient as getting an element in a LinkedList is a sequential traversal that is, O(n).